# Tampermonkey + jQuery. Prevent window.location loaded in script tag

Tags: window.location

I'm running a tampermonkey script on a page that loads a `<script src=..` on its own.

Part of its script uses `window.location`, which I'd like to change to `window.open(..` in a `_blank` window. My script works fine, but it also runs `window.location`

How do I prevent `window.location` from triggering?

Answer (score 0):

The script was using `$(document).delegate(".element", "click", function(){ window.location ...` so I just used `$(document).undelegate(".clickable-element", "click")` and it stopped changing the current window.